# In Yii2 transaction shows Lock wait timeout exceeded while saving in to two databases

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Recently I found the problem, that when I try to save models whose tables are in two databases, web page stalls and after while shows:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO ...

What I have done is that writing another transaction for that database inside first transaction, but I got the same result.

If I save second model after the commit, then no problem, however, I need to save inside transaction.

Here is my code:

```
$transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    if (!parent::save($runValidation, $attributeNames)) {
        throw new \DomainException(static::class . ' is not saved.');
    }
    if (Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin() && static::tableName() == '{{%manage_users}}') {
        $this->saveBranches();
    }
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest && static::tableName() == '{{%manage_users}}') {
        $user_id = User::findOne(['email' => $this->email])->id;
    } else if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest && $insert) {
        $user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    }

    if (static::tableName() === 'manage_purchases') {
        $this->logFiles($this->content_ru . ' ' . $this->content_en . ' ' . $this->content_uz);
        $this->saveTags();
    }

    $log_message = $this->parseActiveRecord($this, $insert, $user_id);
    Logs::log($log_message, $user_id);
    $transaction->commit();
    return true;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    Logs::log($e->getMessage(), $user_id, Logs::EXCEPTION_THROWN);
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
}
```

As you see I'm trying to log changes into another database's table.